# Is there any way to have 2 Open VPN connections at the same time in android 4.1?

Tags: android, vpn, openvpn, tunneling

Question in the topic - due to Android's restriction to one VPNService at a time we are trying to have two of them which are using TUN. Is this even remotely possible?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is impossible, mainly that you can only have one VpnService running at a time. From the documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.html:

> There can be only one VPN connection running at the same time. The existing interface is deactivated when a new one is created.

Now, you can probably run an instance of VpnService and then route the traffic through something alike a proxy server, but I don't see the point of that and you would need to protect the VpnService from reading the routed traffic and ending up in a loop.